# Automate populate values from Excel into a Confluence timeline

Tags: excel

I have a unique situation where I have a list of values with corresponding dates in excel. These dates however can shift and each week I have to manually check through each item and check for date changes. The challenge is that these values are used on a confluence page to build a timeline (a simple table) and it is a tedious task for me to check each value in the timeline against the excel sheet. See examples below:

Excel:

| Values | Date |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | 4/7/2021 |
| Orange | 4/8/2021 |

Timeline:

| 4/7/2021 | 4/8/2021 |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | Orange |

Looking for ideas to automate this where the values are populated live from excel to confluence.

Comment: If each date corresponds to a unique value, you can try **VLOOKUP** or **XLOOKUP** (available in Excel 365) to look up the value based on the date the `confluence` sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you should format your Values-Dates as table. Then just write the dates horizontally. Write this formula under each date as I wrote it in my cell E18:

=FILTER(Table1[Column1],Table1[Column2]=E17)

[image: Check this]

(Of course, you can name the table and column names by yourself.)

By doing this, you ensure that every time you add a new row to your Values-Dates table or change any value, the FILTER formula updates itself and gives you all available results.